# Select certain number of rows from junction table

Tags: php, mysql, select, junction-table

I have 3 tables:

```
table1: stores
columns:id(PK), name, visits

table2: categories
columns: id(PK), name

table3: cat_store
columns: store_id(FK), category_id(FK)
```

There are 27 categories and every store has at least one category. cat_store is the junction table.
What i want to achieve is to get a list of all categories order alphabetically and under each category name to list the first 10 visited stores order by name. Something like this:

```
categories.name1
   stores.name1
   stores.name2
   ....
   stores.name10

categories.name2
   stores.name1
   stores.name2
   ....
   stores.name10
...
categories.name27
   stores.name1
   stores.name2
   ....
   stores.name10
```

Currently i have an array with all categories names. Then in a foreach loop i get the stores for each category. This means 28 queries.

Is there a way to achieve this with less queries?

Thanks in advance!
P.S. Please excuse my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your English is fine.

You can do this with variables, that is probably the most efficient method:

```
select cs.*
from (select c.name as catname, s.name as storename, s.visits,
             @rn := if(@cid = c.id, @rn + 1, if(@cid := c.id, 1, 1)) as rn
      from cat_store cs join
           categories c
           on cs.category_id = c.id join
           stores s
           on cs.store_id = s.id cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @cid := 0) vars
      order by c.id, visits desc
     ) cs
where rn <= 10;
```

Note:  this puts the category as a separate *column* rather than a separate *row* -- which is consistent with the table format for result sets.  You can easily find the category in the first row for each group by using `rn = 1` logic.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I am beginner to MYSQL-PHP. Tried your code in phpmyadmin and get `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`. I don't understand the mysql variables. Kindly ask for more details, or an introduction tutorial.

Comment: @Mirceac21 . . . Oops.  Left outer the table alias for the subquery that defines the variables.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot Gordon.